# Javascript iterate array of strings and add typing/deleting effect to each, completing one after the other

Tags: javascript, html, css

The component I am making is meant to type out and then delete a list of strings.
Currently, I have the typing/deleting effect. However, I can not get the loop to operate correctly.

The desired effect is to type + untype the first string, THEN the second, THEN the third etc.

```js
var pos = 0
var speed = 50
var speed2 = 100
var str = document.getElementById('str')
var i

var messages = [
    "Cyber Security",
    "Vulnerability Assessments",
    "Program Management",
    "Compliance Management"
]

messages.forEach(function (message) {

    function type() {
        console.log('Type ' + pos)
        if (pos < message.length) {
            str.innerText += message.charAt(pos)
            pos++
            setTimeout(type, speed) //call this fn again to type letters
        } else {
            setTimeout(erase, speed2)
        }
    }

    type(type, speed)

    //erase fn
    function erase() {
        console.log('Erase ' + pos)
        if (pos >= 0) {
            var temp = message.substring(0, pos)
            str.innerText = temp
            pos--
            setTimeout(erase, speed2)
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<section class="hollow-hero-21">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <h1>
            Innovative Solutions
            <br>for
            <span id="str"></span>
        </h1>
        <hr>
        <p>This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available. This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available.</p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Well, you start all your typings and erasings at the same time. I would say you don't need the `messages.forEach` block and just check in the `erase` method wether there is a next element in your array and when yes, start typing that one. It would only require to keep an index to your current element you are typing / erasing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you have the problem that you start all the typing and sub sequential removing at the same time, due to your `messages.forEach` loop.

There is no need for this loop, as you want to wait till each word has been typed and removed. So you would need to remember the index of your current message as long as you are typing it and removing it, and then update it after the last word has been removed.

I changed your script so that the loop has been removed, and there is only 1 action at the moment, with a bit flag saying it `isRemoving`. Personally, I would rather do it with a `setInterval` but to not alter your desired behavior, I added the `setTimeout` instead.

This version will run indefinitely, as after the last word from the array is removed, it will go back to the first message in your array.

```js
var speed = 50;
var speed2 = 100;
var str = document.getElementById('str');
var i = 0;
var isRemoving = false;

var messages = [
    "Cyber Security",
    "Vulnerability Assessments",
    "Program Management",
    "Compliance Management"
]

function action() {
  if (isRemoving) {
    if (str.innerText.length > 0) {
      str.innerText = str.innerText.substr(0, str.innerHTML.length - 1);
      setTimeout( action, speed2 );
      return;
    }
    isRemoving = false;
    i++;
    if (i >= messages.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout( action, speed );
    return;
  }
  var message = messages[i];
  str.innerText = message.substr(0, str.innerHTML.length + 1);
  if (str.innerText.length === message.length) {
    isRemoving = true;
  }
  setTimeout( action, isRemoving ? speed2 : speed );
}

setTimeout( action, speed ) ;
```

```html
<section class="hollow-hero-21">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <h1>
            Innovative Solutions
            <br>for
            <span id="str"></span>
        </h1>
        <hr>
        <p>This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available. This is filler content. The text in this area will be replaced when copy for the site becomes available.</p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Icepickle. After adding a couple details, I got this working the way I wanted with your solution.